# Zend_form_element_radio can't add class to label

Tags: php, zend-framework, radio-button, label, zend-form

I'm trying to add a class (the same) to each label in a group of radio buttons.

This is my code:

```
$linkedin_share = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('linkedin_share', array('escape' => false));
    $linkedin_share->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper','Errors', array('Label', array('class' => 'TEST'))))
                ->addMultiOption('none', $this->getView()->translate('None'))
                ->addMultiOption('icon', '<img src="'.$this->getView()->baseUrl().'/images/admin/icons/social_media_share/linkedin.png'.'"/>')
                ->addMultiOption('counter', '<img src="'.$this->getView()->baseUrl().'/images/admin/icons/social_media_share/linkedin_share.jpg'.'"/>')
                ->setSeparator('')
                ->setAttrib('class', 'item_small_checkbox');
```

And this is my output:

```
<label for="linkedin_share-none">
<label for="linkedin_share-icon">
<label for="linkedin_share-counter">
```

This is my desired output:

```
<label for="linkedin_share-none" class="share_label_class">
<label for="linkedin_share-icon" class="share_label_class">
<label for="linkedin_share-counter" class="share_label_class">
```

The stupid thing is that it works for all my other form elements so far. I tried a million combinations and searched my ass off, but no matter what I try I can't add class to the label.

Ideas, solutions, suggestions are all very welcome! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you give us the code of the elements for wich it works ? I would try to look at what's different in between those, or what's different in the form of the elements that are working (if it's not the same).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It took me two hours to find the answer and it's infuriatingly simple! Add this line to your declaration:-

```
->setAttrib('label_class', 'share_label_class')
```

Zend/View/Helper/FormRadio.php line 79 - 95 gave me the clue.

```
   $label_attribs = array();
    foreach ($attribs as $key => $val) {
        $tmp    = false;
        $keyLen = strlen($key);
        if ((6 < $keyLen) && (substr($key, 0, 6) == 'label_')) {
            $tmp = substr($key, 6);
        } elseif ((5 < $keyLen) && (substr($key, 0, 5) == 'label')) {
            $tmp = substr($key, 5);
        }

        if ($tmp) {
            // make sure first char is lowercase
            $tmp[0] = strtolower($tmp[0]);
            $label_attribs[$tmp] = $val;
            unset($attribs[$key]);
        }
    }
```

This works on my system, I hope it does for you too.

Comment: Wow! So incredibly simple! Thanks a lot! It's a bummer that ZF really lacks a lot in documentation at some points.

Comment: Yeah, the best documentation is the code. It's well written, so you can usually work things out eventually. Thanks for the interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$linkedin_share = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('linkedin_share', array('escape' => false));
$linkedin_share->setAttrib('class', 'item_small_checkbox');
    $linkedin_share->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper','Errors', array('Label', array('class' => 'TEST'))))
                ->addMultiOption('none', $this->getView()->translate('None'))
                ->addMultiOption('icon', '<img src="'.$this->getView()->baseUrl().'/images/admin/icons/social_media_share/linkedin.png'.'"/>')
                ->addMultiOption('counter', '<img src="'.$this->getView()->baseUrl().'/images/admin/icons/social_media_share/linkedin_share.jpg'.'"/>')
                ->setSeparator('');
```

OR

//linkedin_share

```
$this->addElement(
    'radio',
    'linkedin_share',
    array(
         'label' => 'Linkedin Share',
         'separator' => ' ',
         'class' => 'item_small_checkbox',
    )
);
$this->linkedin_share->addMultiOption('none', $this->getView()->translate('None'))
        ->addMultiOption('icon', '<img src="' . $this->getView()->baseUrl() . '/images/admin/icons/social_media_share/linkedin.png' . '"/>')
        ->addMultiOption('counter', '<img src="' . $this->getView()->baseUrl() . '/images/admin/icons/social_media_share/linkedin_share.jpg' . '"/>');
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I already tried applying the decorators in different positions.

Comment: How do you mean? Remove all the other decorators? That didn't work either. I also tried adding all possible decorators.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4030/discussion-between-jellybelly-and-rick-de-graaf)